# ImportError: No module named Adafruit_I2C

Tags: raspbian, python, i2c

This looks like a common problem but it makes no sense to me
I made a test program with "import  Adafruit_I2C" as the only line and I get the Import error. 
I have run 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python-rpi.gpio
sudo python Testpath.py
sudo python 2.7 Testpath.py

Testpath.py is my 1 line file
everything is in my directory /home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_CharLCDPlate

Just solved it
The problem is I edited the file via WinSCP. id does something to the file when it saves it back to the Pi.
If I open adafruit_i2c .py with Nano it's empty, so I cut and pasted it in and it works
Looks like I need to look into the default editor from WinSCP

Frustrated beginner needs help

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it The problem is I edited the file via WinSCP. id does something to the file when it saves it back to the Pi. If I open adafruit_i2c.py with Nano it's empty, so I cut and pasted it in and it works Looks like I need to look into the default editor from WinSCP